# Connect android app to an External MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql, http

I have created a login_activity for my android app. I've gone through quite a few tutorials on how to fetch data from an external MySQL database. I have access to this external MySQL database. I've followed one of them to write the following PHP code which will fetch my data from the server for my login_Activity:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING);

$dbhost="localhost";
$dbuser="";   
$dbpass=""

$connect=mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbsuer,$dbpass) or die("database selection error");

$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM app_users_parent where Email='$username' AND Password='$password');
$num=mysql_num_rows($query);

if($num==1) {

while($list=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
$output=$list;
echo json_encode('$output');
}

mysql_close();

}

?>
```

I understand I've got to place this php file onto the same server. But I don't really understand how to do that? Should I use something like FileZilla for FTP or what? 
I could not find any tutorial on the net which shows how and where to save this php file.
If you need my Java code where I'm connecting to this file,I could give it to you. 
(P.S.- I just started with android so not really a pro out here. Please respect that )

Answer (score 0):

[How to connect Android with PHP, MySQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) tutorial definitely help you. Good luck.

Comment: Oh yes,I have checked this already. I'm running this app on an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. What would be the changes? Do I have to use LAMP instead of WAMP?

Comment: Just tell me,what are the extra things I need? I've got one php file to connect to the server,a java class to talk to this php file and an external database on the same server where I need to put this php file.

Do I need to upload the php file onto the server via some FTP ? If yes,which one would you recommend?

Comment: @Zepp93: Install XAMPP and no need to upload that file, just download that source code and import source code into eclipse and then run by just changing URL as your IP addresss.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to upload your .php file onto your server (wich contain the MySQL database).

Then, in you android class, create an asynctask class. That aynsctask class have to request your phpfile an get the json.

Comment: I'm not using asynctask class to request the php file. I'm using httppost to send the nameValuePair (username and password) and then parsing the json response

Comment: First, yes you need to upload your file via FTP using FileZilla. Are you using a dedicated server ? 

Then, if you are note using an AsynTask, you gonna get error because you can do that on the man thread. Android, since Honeycomb, doesn't allow "mainthreadnetwork" anymore. ;)

Comment: This startup I'm working for has its database hosted on this particular server. Okay so I need FileZilla for FTP. Do I need anything else? Do I need to install LAMP onto my system(I'm using Ubuntu 12.04LTS) or just transfer the file using FileZilla onto the server?
Btw,thanks a lot for replying! Really appreciate your help.

Comment: The server gonna need Lamp or not but PHP5, MySQL (for the database) and phpmyadmin if you wanna administrate the DB with UI, not in command line.

Comment: Right now,what should be my next step? I exported my php file using FileZilla directly from my local workspace(do I need to export it from LAMP Or something?),but my android app stops executing. It works fine without the http commands but when I'm trying to connect to the server,it stops

Comment: Where is located your .php file ? 
It should be in /var/www/afloader/file.php to be reachable. 
If the connection doesn't work, check you login/mdp of DB in your .php file.

Comment: It is out there. But in this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-ymoagI0MM ,it says that I should have it in my LAMP/www (it says wamp since it's in Windows.) Is it the same folder? I've installed LAMP but can't find LAMP/var/www. I kept the file in /var/www. But now I don't know the role of phpmyadmin here. I understand it's useful to create tables and all. But how should I deal with it? I've got it installed too

Comment: No phpmyadmin is juste usefull to create your database.
But you are asking here How to use external database but do you have your database ? (with tables etc)